# Xamarin Forms - Saving object to access it later

Tags: json, xamarin.forms, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am using Xamarin Forms with Newtonsoft.JSON and Xam.Plugin.Settings plugins to save IDevice object as JSON to use it later. 
First page:

```
private async void SelectBluetoothDevice(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string device = JsonConvert.SerializeObject((IDevice) e.SelectedItem);
    AppSettings.AddOrUpdateValue("device", device);
    await Navigation.PopAsync();
}
```

Here I simply make selected item to JSON string and save it. It works like it should be.
But the problem im facing comes whenever I try to deserialize from saved string.

```
string device = AppSettings.GetValueOrDefault("device", "");
if (!device.Equals(""))
{
    Debug.WriteLine(device);
    // This line produces error
    IDevice dev = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IDevice>(device);
    settingsDeviceName.Text = dev.Name;
}
```

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Could not create an
>   instance of type Plugin.BLE.Abstractions.Contracts.IDevice. Type is an
>   interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated. Path
>   'BluetoothDevice', line 1, position 19.

So I understand that IDevice is interface and my JSON string cant be deserialized nothing but into object. Any good ideas how to workaround it? Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you to deserialize it to an instantiable object like 'BluetoothDevice'  as the exception message suggest it... I'm pretty sure your method "SelectBluetoothDevice()" will only get you back "BluetoothDevice" objects... So why to cast it into IDevice ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IDevice>(device);` basically does this:

- Read the JSON in `device`
- Try to create the type of object you want to deserialize to, in this case, `IDevice`
- Return you the new object with all the properties filled

The problem is with step 2. You can't create an instance of an interface. So you need to deserialize to a concrete object that implements `IDevice`.